GMAT edit object fields in Mission Sequence
I am trying to change the ISP of an Impulsive Burn during the Mission Sequence.
But why so ever, GMAT does not allow me to do so? I looked at the source code as well, and I do not see any indicators (e.g. private of this Field, etc.).
Does anyone have a clue?
%----------------------------------------
%---------- Burns
%----------------------------------------

Create ImpulsiveBurn IMP_reboost_burn_PROP;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.CoordinateSystem = Local;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Origin = Earth;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Axes = VNB;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Element1 = 0;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Element2 = 0;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Element3 = 0;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.DecrementMass = true;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Tank = {Starlab_fuel_tank_PROP};
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Isp = 100;
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.GravitationalAccel = 9.81;


....
....
....

%----------------------------------------
%---------- Mission Sequence
%----------------------------------------

BeginMissionSequence;
...
GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Isp = 100;

Error message is, when I try to save the script:
Interpreting scripts from the file.
***** file: .... **** ERROR **** GmatBase Exception Thrown: The Moderator cannot create a Parameter type "Isp" named "IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Isp"
 in the line:
   " 355: GMAT IMP_reboost_burn_PROP.Isp = 100;"

I do this with all other kinds of parameters, but the Isp of the burn does not work. Or am I just very stupid here?
Cheers, Alex

Unfortunately, some of the properties in GMAT just aren't accessible in the mission sequence, so in short, no you are not stupid. It is odd that the Isp isn't able to be set/get since its labeled as having those accesses in the User Guide, but upon inspection of the source code it appears that the Isp property is protected for the ImpulsiveBurn object, which is likely why it not change-able. If its something you think they should expose, I would suggest adding a ticket to the GMAT Jira Page.
I've run into this before as well, unfortunately the private and protected properties aren't very clear until you try to access them.
